# Scrollspy error: Wrong nav item activated

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am working on a bootstrap landing page using scrollspy:

```
// ScrollSpy
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '' });
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
    var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
});
```

But instead of highlighting the current nav items correctly (adding the CSS `active` class), it highlights the next (or the next but one) item. What does invoke this error and how can I stop it?

The site with error is [trapimo.org](http://www.trapimo.org).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add target like:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar-example' })
```

it is all explained in [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

---

For a general bootstrap installation:

Add scrollspy behavior to your topbar navigation, add `data-spy="scroll"` to the element you want to spy on (most typically this would be the `body`). Then add the `data-target` attribute with the ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap `.nav` component.

Check the examples in doc on `data-attr`.

Comment: Thanks for your information: I couldn't find any explanation, what the `target` parameter changes.

Comment: No, this didn't solve the problem. Still same behaviour.